# Prove that function is bijective if $f^n = id_A$ for $n \geq 2$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A \neq \varnothing$ and $f: A \rightarrow A$. Also let $f^n = id_A$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ and $n \geq 2$. ($id_A$ being the identity function on $A$).

Here is my solution, but I have doubts about some steps

For $n = 2$ we get $(f \circ f) (a) = f(f(a)) = id_A(a)$. Does this then imply $f(f(a)) = f(a)$ ? If yes, then we get $f(a) = f(f(a)) = id_A(a) = a \space$, for all a $\in A$. This basically proves that $f$ is surjective.

For injectivity we can use (above proven fact) that $f = id_A$. Since $f^{-1}(f(a)) = f^-1(a) = a \space \forall a \in A$, $f$ is injective.

Therefore $f$ is bijective.

Is this reasoning valid? Thanks

Comment: Do you know that a function is bijective if and only if it is Invertible?

Comment: @GBA I didn't have in mind that equivalence when I approached this proof, but yeah sure. I guess you are saying it can be proven by using that?

Comment: Yes, as $f^{(n-1)}\circ f=f\circ f^{(n-1)}=id_A$.

Comment: "Does this then imply $f(f(a))=f(a)$?" No, there is no reason for that to be true. A simple counterexample is $f(x) = -x$ defined on $A = \Bbb R$. There are lots of functions other than the identity for which $f^n$ is the identity map for some $n$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks! feel free to make your comment an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I would consider GBA's comment on how to actually prove the result more helpful. $f$ must be bijective because $id_A$ is bijective. For any $a \in A, f(f^{n-1}(a)) = a$, so its surjective, and if $f(a) = f(b)$, then $a = f^{n-1}(f(a)) = f^{n-1}(f(b)) = b$, so its injective.

Comment: @PaulSinclair his comment is definitely helpful and appreciated but you addressed my question, so that's why I prefer your answer. Thanks for the elaboration